# How to properly test a debounced function in an asynchronous React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, mocha.js, enzyme

My react component runs an asynchronous query to obtain some data using [lodash debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce) - since user input can cause re-queries and I want to rate-limit the queries - and then sets the state of the component with the results that are returned.

**MyComponent** (React Component)

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.runQuery();
}

handler = (response) => {
   this.setState({ results: response.results });
}

runQuery = _.debounce((props = this.props) => {
  // run the query
  doStuff(mainParams)
    .withSomeOtherStuff(moreParams)
    .query()
    .then(this.handler)
    .catch((error) => {
      this.props.catchError(error);
    });
}, 200);
```

I am currently stubbing out my main api exit point that goes out and fetches the data which returns a promise thanks to the `sinon-stub-promise` package

```
before((done) => {
  stub = stubGlobalFn('evaluate'); // returns stubbed promise, uses npm:sinon-stub-promise
});
```

This allows me the ability to use my custom Reader (tested elsewhere) to read in a mock response and then resolve it synchronously for testing purposes.

**mytest.spec.jsx**

```
  let stub;
  const testWithProps = props => (
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      new Reader(histories).readGrid((err, grid) => {
        try {
          expect(err).to.be.a('null');
          stub.resolves(grid);
          // ....
```

Then in the same `testWithProps` function I'm able to mount the `Table` component with the props I specify in my test as sort of a test factory.

```
const wrapper = mount(<Table {...props} />);
```

And here's where I run into my confusion, I have stubbed out the promise that gets resolved when the main `evaluate` async function is invoked but not the state handler.

```
stub.thenable.then(() => {
  // --------------------------
  // PROBLEM: how to test without setting a timeout?
  // --------------------------
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(wrapper.update());
  }, 200);
  // --------------------------
  // --------------------------
});
```

Should I be stubbing my `handler` function inside of my react component instead if I'm wanting to test the state of the component *after* the async behavior? I'm not sure how to even stub that part out if that's even what's needed.

Ultimately my test looks like this by the end:

```
it('toggles the row for the value when clicked', () => {
  const props = {
    // some props that I use
  };

  return testWithProps(props).then((wrapper) => {
    // simply testing that my mocked response made it in successfully to the rendered component
    expect(wrapper.state().results.length).to.equal(4);
  });
});
```